# In any ring R, show that ab is nilpotent iff ba is nilpotent. Can one say the same for zero divisors?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, nilpotence

I tried it this way...
$(ab)^{n}=o$ then $a(ba)^{n-1}b=0$ but then we can't conclude anything from this as a and b may not have inverses..

Thanks for any help!!

Comment: Hint: Consider $b(ab)^na$.

Comment: As for the second question in the title (terrible idea to put questions in the title but not in the body, btw) the answer is "no": you can have, for example, $ab=1$ but $ba$ be a zero divisor.

Answer (score 3):

Try it the other way around: If $(ab)^n = 0$ then $b(ab)^na = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

$(ab)^n=0$ implies $b(ab)^na=(ba)^{n+1}=0$.

Answer (score 0):

if $a = 0$ or $b = 0$ you have nothing to do because $ab = 0 = ba$, so supose that $a$ and $b$ are diferent of zero, in that case you have $a(ba)^{n-1}b = 0$, and $a,b$ diferent of zero so $(ba)^{n-1} = 0$ and thats the definition of being nilpotent.